# Parseo de un archivo para guardar datos en una lista

Tags: python

tengo un archivo.txt con la siguiente información:

```
NE : Equipo1

 SN  RN PN  Fan name  temperature

 0   0  0    FAN1      34/93.2                                
 0   0  0    FAN2      35/95.0                                

NE : Equipo2

 SN  RN PN  Fan name  temperature

 0   0  0    FAN1      36/93.2                                
 0   0  0    FAN2      333/95.0
```

Y quiero guardar en una variable los nombres de los equipos y los valores de temperatura.

Armé el siguiente código:

```py
import re
import pathlib

ruta = str(pathlib.Path().absolute()) + "/archivo.txt"
with open(ruta, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:    
    for lineas in f:
       
        NE = []
        if "NE : " in lineas:
            sitios = lineas[5:].split()
            NE += sitios
            print(NE[0])
```

Con este código obtengo la siguiente salida:

```
Equipo1

Equipo2
```

Pero quisiera tenerla en una lista de esta forma para poder iterarla:
`['Equipo1','Equipo2']`

No le puedo encontrar la vuelta. Alguno me puede dar una mano?
Gracias!

Comment: mueve tu variable `NE` fuera del `for`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en cada iteración se vuelve a crear (o sobrescribir) tu variable `NE` esto por que está dentro de un ciclo `for`. La solución es ponerlo fuera de este.

```py
with open(ruta, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:   
    NE = []
    for lineas in f:
        if "NE : " in lineas:
            sitios = lineas[5:].split()
            NE += sitios
            # print(NE[0])
print(NE)
```

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es poner todo eso en una función y luego retornar una variable (`NE`), así estará todo más ordenado y se verá mejor :)

Comment: Gracias Christian! Hago una consulta más pq se me está complicando. Yo por cada equipo quiero imprimir líneas diferentes para que me quede identificado cada equipo con cada ubicacion y su valor de temperatura, es decir, necesito obtener una salida de esta forma:                                                                                  
Equipo1 0   0  0    FAN1      34/93.2                                
Equipo1 0   0  0    FAN2      35/95.0                                

Equipo2 0   0  0    FAN1      36/93.2                                
Equipo2 0   0  0    FAN2      333/95.0

Comment: No sé cuál es la forma en cómo lo haces, es mejor que hagas otra pregunta y que muestras la forma en que extraes la info. Se me ocurren formas más fácil pero todo depende de cual es elnproceso que estés haciendo